# Google Map API throwing JS error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Trying to animate a line and I have figure out most of the code. I am getting an error and not sure why?

Here is error logged into the console. You can see where it goes wrong.

CONSOLE LOG:

```
     c is (30.37470457, -97.76039932000003)
     get at depature is (30.37470457, -97.76039932000003)
     get at arrival is (30.39386213, -97.75522519000003)
     path is path.getPath() [object Object]
     steps is running
     are we there yet is(30.374781200646034, -97.76037862752048)
     steps is running
    js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined_.Ob @ js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:38Gy.interpolate @ js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:125(anonymous function) @ 
     steps is running
    js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined_.Ob @ js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:38Gy.interpolate @ js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:125(anonymous function) @ 
     steps is running
    js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:38 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined_.Ob @ js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:38Gy.interpolate @ js?key=secret&sensor=false&libraries=geometry:125(anonymous function) @ 
     steps is running
```

JS CODE:

```
    function drawPath2(run_id){
  var request = $.ajax({
    url: "/requester/potrip?r_id=" + r_id,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json"
  });

  request.done(function(data) {
    console.log("starting request done");
    var p = data['points'];
    var c = [];
    var bounds = new goog.LatLngBounds();
    for(var i = 0; i < p.length; i++){
      var l = new goog.LatLng(parseFloat(p[i][1]), parseFloat(p[i][0]));
      bounds.extend(l);

      c.push(l);
    }

    console.log("c is " + c);
    console.log("c is " + c[0]);
    departure = parseFloat(c[0][1]);
      arrival = parseFloat(c[c.length-1][0]);
    var path = createPoly(c, "head");
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    path.setMap(null);

console.log("get at depature is " + path.getPath().getAt(0));
console.log("get at arrival is " + path.getPath().getAt(path.getPath().getLength()-1));
console.log("path is path.getPath() " + path.getPath());
    var step = 0;
 var numSteps = 250; //Change this to set animation resolution
 var timePerStep = 5; //Change this to alter animation speed
 var theLenght = path.getPath().getLength()-1;
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
     step += 1;
     console.log("steps is running");
     if (step > numSteps) {
      console.log("clearinginterval" + step);
         clearInterval(interval);
     } else {

         var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(path.getPath().getAt(0),path.getPath().getAt(1),step/numSteps);
         console.log("are we there yet is" + are_we_there_yet);
         path.setPath([path.getPath().getAt(0), are_we_there_yet]); <-- ERROR
     }
 }, timePerStep);



  });

  request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
  });
}
```

UPDATE:

After using @geocodezip answer and code I had several syntax issues. I am using his code now, but still not working. I believe it is my data points that are the issue. My points are plots from 3 seconds GPS grabs, not just the begginging and end points. I have updated @geocodezip JSFiddle and you can see when using my data points it draws one dot. If you delete all my data points, but two then it draws a line, but not on the data points I have.

https://jsfiddle.net/rpse4u7q/7/

DATA:

```
      var data = {
  "points": [
        [-97.76039932, 30.37470457],
        [-97.76039773, 30.37470464],
        [-97.76025161, 30.37481161],
        [-97.76048998, 30.3752743],
        [-97.76086747, 30.37543242],
        [-97.76218839, 30.3757006],
        [-97.76345371, 30.37628355],
        [-97.76440906, 30.37738785],
        [-97.76498148, 30.37882327],
        [-97.76550885, 30.38187354],
        [-97.76606298, 30.38390495],
        [-97.76639823, 30.38462131],
        [-97.76633701, 30.38513405],
        [-97.7652047, 30.38599167],
        [-97.76364974, 30.38714456],
        [-97.76177313, 30.38802739],
        [-97.76056218, 30.38809251],
        [-97.76013834, 30.38807344],
        [-97.75972944, 30.38843747],
        [-97.75970029, 30.38948685],
        [-97.75958011, 30.39068898],
        [-97.75859334, 30.39140352],
        [-97.75722475, 30.39161915],
        [-97.75636673, 30.3926098],
        [-97.75564576, 30.39375132],
        [-97.75525439, 30.39416341],
        [-97.75484361, 30.39382476],
        [-97.75508556, 30.39377933],
        [-97.75523972, 30.39385163],
        [-97.75522519, 30.39386213]
    ]
}

var olddata = {
  points: [
    [-72, 42],
    [-73, 43]
  ]
};
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error. From the error, I would say that path.getPath().getAt(0) (or are_we_there_yet) is undefined.

Comment: Looks like whatever you're passing into `google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate` is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logic issue.  You can't use the path of the polyline to contain the final value of the path and the interpolated value.  Once you have run the animation once it gets stuck at a zero length polyline.

This code works for me:

```
var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(
                         c[0], 
                         c[1], 
                         step / numSteps);
path.setPath([c[0], are_we_there_yet]);
```

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  animatePolyline(data);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);


function animatePolyline(data) {
  // input data
  var p = data.points;
  // array of google.maps.LatLng objects
  var c = [];
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    var l = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(p[i][1]), parseFloat(p[i][0]));
    bounds.extend(l);

    c.push(l);
  }

  var path = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: [],
    map: map
  });
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  path.setMap(map);

  var step = 0;
  var numSteps = 250; //Change this to set animation resolution
  var timePerStep = 5; //Change this to alter animation speed
  var theLength = path.getPath().getLength() - 1;
  var interval = setInterval(function() {
    step += 1;
    if (step > numSteps) {
      clearInterval(interval);
    } else {
      var are_we_there_yet = google.maps.geometry.spherical.interpolate(c[0], c[1], step / numSteps);
      path.setPath([c[0], are_we_there_yet]);
    }
  }, timePerStep);
}


var data = {
  points: [
    [-72, 42],
    [-73, 43]
  ]
};
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>

<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Can you link to a JSFiddle as I tried your above code in a Fiddle and it flashes the screen white and nothing happens.

Comment: Where is that fiddle (where you tried the code)? The code snippet works for me in Chrome.

Comment: That fiddle is just configured incorrectly [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rpse4u7q/4/)

Comment: I copied your code. Can you provide the link to yours.

Comment: You are asking for a link to the code snippet in my answer?

Comment: Or another link to [the fixed version of yours](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rpse4u7q/4/)?

Comment: Still tells me "a.lat is not a function" when used with my data. My data is finde as if I don't use your code then the line gets drawn just not animated.

Comment: What browser/debugger?  I don't see that error in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rpse4u7q/4/) or the code snippet in my answer in Chrome.  Do you have a fiddle that exhibits that error?

Comment: Do you have more than two vertices in your polyline?

Comment: Ok so I have compeletly swapped out my code for most of yours. And after hours of work I think the issue is my data. It isn't an array. Not sure what it is. Updating with the console output of my data.

Comment: My data is the issue. I have 30 points of x,y and the code seems to only want a start and end not every point. I need the code to use all my points to draw along where the person ran/walked.

Comment: See my data above vs. your data.

Comment: Ok fixed it!!!!! Here is the JSFiddle. Weird I had to update yours. If I create my own JSFiddle with the same code as your it won't load?   https://jsfiddle.net/rpse4u7q/10/

Comment: Ok fixed it!!!!! Here is the JSFiddle. Weird I had to update yours. If I create my own JSFiddle with the same code as your it won't load?   https://jsfiddle.net/rpse4u7q/10/

Comment: I had to change some of the meta options in the fiddle to get it to work (it isn't only the code)

Comment: Cool.  Your approach will work as long as the polyline has vertices that are reasonably close together.  If there are long straight stretches it will jump/move quick across them (if I understand your code correctly, you are just iterating through the "c" array, adding each point on to the growing polyline).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96936/discussion-between-jdog-and-geocodezip).

Comment: Example of what I am talking about: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rpse4u7q/11/)